# Universal links opening app but not fetching url data

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

Implemented every kind of step exactly as described. App open successfully but, no URL data fetched.

Implemented every kind of step exactly as described. Send links from gmail and the links open the app so yes, it works. 
BUT here is 2 problems

1- How on earth can I debug and print the app since you have to close the app and break the connection between the app and Xcode debugger to reopen the app from a universal link !!. It's frustrating, If I keep the app running in the background for the debugger, the universal link simply re- activates the app state to the foreground but then the function 
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:  ....

is not invoked

2- I always get "userActivity?.activityType" = nil no matter what.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
 if userActivity?.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb {
            let univrsalLinkURL = userActivity?.webpageURL!.absoluteString
//            remoteParmNumTxt = univrsalLinkURL!
            print(univrsalLinkURL!)
        }
return true
}
```

Should be able to capture url and url data
iOS 12.4
Xcode 10.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after many trials trying to get the app run and fetch url data
It seems like something has changed in iOS where "userActivity" will always be nil unless you get it from an overload from "application" function

so @Simon McLoughlin solution did solve half of the problem by suggesting to use this function

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
             continue userActivity: NSUserActivity,
             restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool
```

But this overload gets triggered "Only" when the app is already running in the background.

Well, the only solution worked for me to get the app to fetch url data if the app is opened by a universal link while its not running is the following

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {

    let activityDictionary = launchOptions?[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.userActivityDictionary] as? [AnyHashable: Any] ?? [AnyHashable: Any]()
    let activity = activityDictionary ["UIApplicationLaunchOptionsUserActivityKey"] as? NSUserActivity ?? nil

    if let finalString = activity?.webpageURL?.absoluteString {
        remoteParmNumTxt = finalString
    }

    print("dic",activity?.webpageURL)
    print("yesssss loaded from url")

    return true
}
```

If you try to use the "userActivity" directly it would give you nil value no matter what

So, apple documentation sucks

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't work for me on iOS 13.4. The launchOptions parameter is nil...

Comment: @Benoît Any solution you found? I am facing the same issue my launchOptions is nil

Comment: @Vijay Nothing :(

Answer (score 2):

The apple documentation on how to handle universal links says to use a different application function to the one you are using. `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` will only be called once when the app is completely closed, leading to the issues you are already facing.

However:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 continue userActivity: NSUserActivity,
                 restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool
```

Will be called whether app is closed or not, later on, when a universal link is triggered. Try using this instead.

Full apple documentation is here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/inter-process_communication/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/handling_universal_links

Comment: the function you stated in the answer do work when the app is running in the background and you simply trigger the Universal Link. Unfortunately, it is not invoked when the app first runs. And it seems like "userActivity" is nil when trying to access it from the "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" function .. so am stuck again

Comment: I kept seeing nil in the debugger. Later I found it was the issue with the debugger itself. Unfortunately console output didn't show anything and action alert didn't work for me neither. But userActivity.webpageURL was actually good. Keep in mind this method is probably called after the view is created.

Answer (score 2):

IOS version > 13.0

only running app (from universal link)

SceneDelegate.swift

```swift
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    ...

    if let activity: NSUserActivity = connectionOptions.userActivities.first,
       let url: URL = activity.webpageURL {
          print(url.absoluteString)
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> 1- How on earth can I debug and print the app

Edit your scheme and select "wait for executable to be launched"

Then, implement `func application(:continue:restorationHandler:)` and check `userActivity.webpageURL` to determine what you need to do.

Comment: Thanks @Gereon,
"wait for executable to be launched" worked for me but I can't see any output from print(..)  on the output window

Comment: same here like what @Moos got.